# Node-mailer: Problem with rendering node mail images in the body; bug ID: 146469

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, scheduler, nodemailer

There is an intermediate problem with some mails having a partially rendered image that comes in the mail body using nodemailer.

```
htmlForMailBody += '<div>' + txt.split("$reportname").join(reportName).split("$sddate").join(reportStartDate).split("$eddate").join(reportEndDate).split("$genDateTime").join(getDateForReports()) + '</div><br><div> URL = <a href=' + genURLFile + '>' + genURLFile + '</a></div><br>';
         if (chartImagePathArr != undefined && chartImagePathArr.length > 0) {
             htmlForMailBody += '<div>';
             for (let i = 0; i < chartImagePathArr.length; i++) {
                 let chartImgPathObj = chartImagePathArr[i]['imgPath'];
                 let obj = {
                     path: ipPort + chartImgPathObj,
                     cid: 'chartImage_' + i
                 }
                 attachmentsArray.push(obj);
                 chartImagePathArr[i].rptSetName = undoReplaceName(chartImagePathArr[i].rptSetName) + "...";

                 if (chartImagePathArr.length > 3) {
                     if (chartImagePathArr.length % 2 == 0)
                         htmlForMailBody += '<div style=\'padding:3px;width:50%;box-sizing:border-box;float:left\'><label style=\'background:#081f3c;color:#fff;font-size:12px;padding:2px;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:100%\'>' + chartImagePathArr[i].rptSetName + '</label><img src=cid:chartImage_' + i + ' ></div>';
                     else {
                         if (i == chartImagePathArr.length - 1)
                             htmlForMailBody += '<div style=\'padding:3px;box-sizing:border-box\'><label style=\'background:#081f3c;color:#fff;font-size:12px;padding:2px;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:100%\'>' + chartImagePathArr[i].rptSetName + '</label><img src=cid:chartImage_' + i + ' ></div>';
                         else
                             htmlForMailBody += '<div style=\'padding:3px;width:50%;box-sizing:border-box;float:left\'><label style=\'background:#081f3c;color:#fff;font-size:12px;padding:2px;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:100%\'>' + chartImagePathArr[i].rptSetName + '</label><img src=cid:chartImage_' + i + '></div>';
                     }

                 } else
                     htmlForMailBody += '<div style=\'padding:3px;box-sizing:border-box\'><label style=\'background:#081f3c;color:#fff;font-size:12px;padding:2px;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:100%\'>' + chartImagePathArr[i].rptSetName + '</label><img src=cid:chartImage_' + i + '></div>';

             }
             htmlForMailBody += '</div>';
         }

         if (attachmentsArray.length > 0) {
             schedulerLog("Creating Mail Option with attachments", 1);
             mailOptions = {
                 html: htmlForMailBody,
                 from: global.mailConfInfo['user'], // sender address
                 to: mailObj.to, // list of receivers
                 subject: sub.split("$reportname").join(reportName).split("$sddate").join(reportStartDate).split("$eddate").join(reportEndDate).split("$genDateTime").join(getDateForReports()), // Subject line
                 attachments: attachmentsArray
             };
         } else {
             schedulerLog("Creating Mail Option without attachments", 1);
             mailOptions = {
                 html: htmlForMailBody,
                 from: global.mailConfInfo['user'], // sender address
                 to: mailObj.to, // list of receivers
                 subject: sub.split("$reportname").join(reportName).split("$sddate").join(reportStartDate).split("$eddate").join(reportEndDate).split("$genDateTime").join(getDateForReports()) // Subject line
             };
         }

         let msStartDate = new Date();
         console.error("send mail StartDate time for checing delay", msStartDate);

         msStartDate = new Date();
         console.error("setTimeout checing delay time :", msStartDate);
         transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
             try {
                 msStartDate = new Date();
                 console.error("setTimeout transporter try block on send mail delay time :", msStartDate);
                 if (typeOfReport == 2) {
                     const fs = require('fs');
                     fs.unlinkSync(filename);  //Removing tar file of HTML Report
                 }
             } catch (err) {
                 console.error("setTimeout transporter catch block on send mail delay time :", msStartDate);
                 schedulerLog("Error on deleting tar file of html report with error Info == " + err, 1);
             }
             if (error) {
                 return schedulerLog("Error in sending mail, error info is = " + JSON.stringify(error), 2);
             }
             schedulerLog("Mail is sent with error Info == " + JSON.stringify(error), 2);
             schedulerLog("Mail is sent with success Info == " + JSON.stringify(info), 1);
         });
```

Note : This problem won't keep coming up. Sometimes it does work.

we want some solution for this and want to know why this issue is comming in mid of mail scheduling.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the actual problem is? What is the current behavior? What is the expected behavior? Node mailer doesn't render anything but mail clients do ...